How to use the RF125-RA (nicerf) module to receive LF data (125 kHz)?
I want to use the RF125-RA module to receive LF antenna data in the car. For initial setup, I use USB to TTL. I put the battery on the module and connected the ground of the module and USB2TTL. In images 
and
.
I expect when I send data from PC to RF125-RA module via UART, it will return OK {0x4F, 0x4B, 0x0D, 0x0A} or Error {0x45, 0x52, 0x52, 0x4F, 0x52, 0x0D, 0x0A} messages. But nothing is returned for any of the messages.
I used the examples from the documentation. I send the command {0x57, 0x05, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x0D, 0x0A} from the PC to the RF125-RA module via USB2TTL. But I do not receive any answer. Photo .
It should be noted that when I press the button on the RF125-RA module once, this module returns the data {0x16,0x0D,0x0A}. Photo
.
How can I use this module?

The {0x16,0x0D,0x0A}  data which is returned by the module when the button on the module is pressed doesn't seem to be described in the RF125 Product Specification. I can't seen any obvious problem with the commands you are sending to module, and they match the documentation. Have you tried asking G-NiceRF for support?
